# Azure function durable - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Value cannot be null. (parameter 'hostConfiguration')

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am working on an dot net core azure function application. We need to implement parallel processing. So I just added "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" using package manager to our existing working application, no other coding done. However when I try to start application using f5, I am getting bellow exception in the console. Has anyone else faced similar issue? Please let me know your thoughts on this.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Value cannot be null. (parameter 'hostConfiguration').

[image: console error]

Comment: What is the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package version referenced in your Azure functions?

Comment: @user1672994 3.0.3

Comment: And I believe you already have host.json file added to your project?

Comment: @user1672994 host.json file is there, but I haven't added anything particular for durable function. Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the real fix or not, however I was able to deal with the exception. Updated azureFunctionsVersion v3 to v4 in .csproj, and installed vs 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Durable Functions relies on a storage account, either in Azure or an emulated one [using Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio). Is there a connectionstring in your `local.settings.json` such as `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` (for emulated storage) and is the emulator running?

Optionally, some default values for Durable Functions can be overridden in the `host.json` as is described in [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio). You could check if there aren't any empty values related to Durable Functions in that file.

Comment: my local.settings.json, AzureWebJobsStorage is pointed to dev environment. Is there any steps we need to follow in azure portal to activate durable functions.

Comment: So locally it runs fine now? Once deployed to Azure the `AzureWebJobsStorage` setting should contain the connectionstring to an Azure Storage Account. By default it should have that since Function Apps depend on a Storage Account.

Comment: Locally I tried with azure storage emulator, and that too not working. I mean Same exception.